# How to disable Adobe Muse СС 2015 update notifications on program startup?

Tags: updates, notifications

There is no option to disable it in the program preferences. I tried to find and disable `Adobe Acrobat Update` service, but i don't have them. I also don't have `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\` or `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\Adobe\Muse` branches in windows registry. I also don't have Adobe Updater or Adobe Application Service. And i don't have `PDApp.exe`. BUT this annoying software notifies me about their damn updates whatever! How can i stop this behavior? I tried to block out connections for Muse.exe in my firewall, but it doesn't help. The version of my Adobe Muse is СС 2015.0.0.597.

Comment: Which version of Muse is this?

Comment: Adobe Muse СС 2015.0.0.597